# I am getting this error when I run the web application

Tags: asp.net

I am getting error when I run the application,

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Web.Extensions,
>   Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

This is the error I am getting  when I run the application, I added the new dll and increased the trust level. Can you help me please.

Comment: The error message comes with a position in your code, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This you try to load on web.config on assembly session is too old (version 1)

Just remove the line from web.config and all is ok, you probably have the Extension again on assembly session from newer version net.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Comment: i remove the linke even though it is coming same problems

Comment: in my systems assemble i have system.web.extension version is 3.5 and publickey=31bf3856ad364e35 but in my application in web.config web.extension is version 1.0.61025 is this problem?

Comment: @Surya Yes this is the problem.